# Laravel production image link

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel-8

I am uploading an image like this in Laravel 8:

```
public function upload(FileRequest $request)
    {
        $image = $request->file('file');

        $fileName = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $image->storeAs('/public/images/', $fileName);

        return
        [
            'path' => asset('/public/images/'.$fileName)
        ];
    }
```

The image get uploaded with the following link: http://{my api url}/public/images/1615123445.JPG.
My API is at api.citynfo.info address. It is stored on server in the api folder. The images got save in {my api folder}/storage/app/public/images folder.

But when I want to read this image in my React application, there is no image returned.
On server i have 3 folders:

- app: there is my React app
- api: thats where is my Laravel public folder
- webApi: thats where my Laravel api is

My question is where and how to save image so I can link it in my React app.

thnx

Comment: Did you run ```php artisan storage:link

Comment: I saw that I need to run it, but how can I run it on server?

Comment: Login to your server and run that command